# Missing some comment notifications on my answer

Tags: support, notifications, global-inbox

I followed [What would you like to change about the moderator election process?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396431/273494) for a while, but the notifications blew up my inbox, so I unfollowed it. I can't find the exact time I unfollowed it, but it was probably Feb 2nd. After that, I stopped receiving notifications of comments posted under my answer. I am receiving notifications for other posts. I am still receiving reputation notifications for that answer.

I'm a bit slammed right now, so haven't had time to try to reproduce it and narrow down why there's no notifications for the couple of comments that happened 2 days ago in my inbox. It's possible I've mistakenly assumed this is due to me unfollowing the post, and there's some other cause. I've looked to see if there's a duplicate, but couldn't easily find one.

Comment: Possible reason is that now\* the notifications for comments on your own answer are grouped. So if you received, say, 10 comments you get one notification. And that notification points to the last comment which can lead you to believe that is the only new one (certainly has tripped me up multiple times). \* the "now" is some time after the new notification with persistent read status was rolled out. Can't remember exactly when this was done, though.

Comment: To clarify, the grouping isn't *only* for new comments on your own posts. But it's one of the places where it applies. It certainly doesn't apply if you follow a post - then you get one separate notification for each comment. Therefore making it extremely confusing because you have to pay attention which post is the notification *for* to figure out if it is about one comment or more.

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ, I was busy all weekend and didn't login to SE. I would expect one of the "two days ago" comments to be in my inbox, but neither are. Oh wait, it IS there... it's probably the grouping then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I missed one of the comments on my post that was buried deeper down than I expected. All of the comments weren't there because of the grouping mentioned by [VLAZ in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396571/unfollowed-a-question-now-im-not-getting-notifications-on-my-answer?noredirect=1#comment1326430_396571), and it confused me.

Comment: Heads-up: I posted a FR to reduce the confusion of this behaviour: [When there are multiple comments on my post, have the notification lead to the oldest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396587). I'm not overly optimistic anything will be done, since [SE seem to have abandoned fixing the notification "improvement"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/391909). This *was* one of the "fixes" they implemented. At any rate, there is at least something tracking what's wrong with it.