# When there are multiple comments on my post, have the notification lead to the oldest

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications, global-inbox

Currently [if multiple comments on one of your own posts, you get a single notification, not multiple](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390795). What happens is that all comment notifications for the same post are grouped together, only the most recent is shown and when it is marked as read, it marks all other notifications in the group as read as well.

However, this makes is hard to actually track comments. [It is too easy to overlook older comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396571/missing-some-comment-notifications-on-my-answer):

- There is no indication that the notification is a "group".
- After follow the most recent notification, the viewport is positioned to show only the last comment and the previous ones are not immediately visible without scrolling up.
- This behaviour is *in stark contrast* with how other comment notifications work if you have followed a post. For those you get one notification per comment, so if you look through the notifications oldest first you are guaranteed to not miss a comment made on a followed post.

To reduce confusion and make it easy for notifications to accurately notify you, at the very least following a grouped comment notification should lead you to the *first* unread comment, so you see the other ones below it, instead of the unread comments being hidden.